# Canonical for page returning error

Tags: error-handling, seo, canonical-link

If for some reason on my website an error occurs, the page will return response 500 and as content it will show some information for the vistor about what happened and where he can continue.

For example:

/product/somebook -> Normal HTTP 200 OK with content about this book

When internal error happens:

/product/somebook -> Error HTTP 500 returns page with information about what to do now (no redirect)

If the reponse is 500 should the page contain a canonical tag to for example /error ?

Comment: The search engine spiders will recognize the 500 HTTP response and will know that you are not serving the correct content, so I am guessing you don't need it.

Comment: Its not so much the errorpage, it's more if the pagerank of the productpage will be splitted because it contains duplicate content now that its 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

An error page, such as 500 or 404 (assuming it is actually served with the appropriate HTTP status code), won't be indexed by a search engine, and no PageRank is attributed, so there's no need to apply a canonical link element to the error page.